# How to Click on content editable div then click on span retain focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the code for the fiddle link 
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/akhilsahu/t7m2nvcn/)

In this the span I click is appended to the content in the div but I want that instead of appending it inserts to the particular location of cursor.

```js
document.querySelector('.selectable-icons').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 
    document.querySelector('[contenteditable]').appendChild(e.target.cloneNode(true));
  
});


document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    // Check for a backspace
    if (event.which == 8) {
        s = window.getSelection();
        r = s.getRangeAt(0)
        el = r.startContainer.parentElement
        // Check if the current element is the .label
        if (el.classList.contains('label')) {
            // Check if we are exactly at the end of the .label element
            if (r.startOffset == r.endOffset && r.endOffset == el.textContent.length) {
                // prevent the default delete behavior
                event.preventDefault();
                if (el.classList.contains('highlight')) {
                    // remove the element
                    el.remove();
                } else {
                    el.classList.add('highlight');
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    event.target.querySelectorAll('span.label.highlight').forEach(function(el) { el.classList.remove('highlight');})
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.4em 0;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height: 1.4em;
  max-width: 1.4em;
}
.selectable-icons img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

span.label.highlight {
    background: #E1ECF4;
    border: 1px dotted #39739d;
}
```

```html
<p>Just click on an icon to add it.</p>

<div class="custom-input">
  <div class="selectable-icons">
    <span class="label"> Ingredient1 </span> 
    <span class="label">INGREDIENT 2</span> 
      <span class="label">INGREDIENT 3</span>  
  </div>
  <div contenteditable="true">
    You can type here. Add an icon.
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried the one solution suggested in this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div)

In the provided link there's a button I used span instead. When I click on span the

```
window.getSelection
```

returns the span element with onClick event. The focus shifts to that span

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064089/inserting-a-text-where-cursor-is-using-javascript-jquery) should work for you.

Comment: Click event is on span

Comment: yes I know. you want to add the clicked item at the current cursor position right?

Comment: Yup I need to add click items

Comment: ok. How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873350/insert-a-string-in-a-textarea-at-cursor-position-with-some-changes

Answer (score 0):

To be able to insert your element at the cursor position, you need to save the current position before the focus is lost. and then on click you need to restore that position before you add the element.
I've updated your JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t7m2nvcn/12/)

```
function saveSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            return sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        return document.selection.createRange();
    }
    return null;
}

function restoreSelection(range) {
    if (range) {
        if (window.getSelection) {
            sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        } else if (document.selection && range.select) {
            range.select();
        }
    }
}

function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.insertNode(html);
            restoreSelection(range);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    }

}
```

You can have a look here for [the full paste html method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-caret-in-a-contenteditable-div)

I hope this helps.