# Prevent keypress default value when user types

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace a with b but i always see a before b.  I tried it with other events like keyup, keydown, event.preventDefault but neither of them worked. How can i prevent this "a" view when user types ?

```js
$("#text").keypress(function(event) {
  text2 = $(this).val();
  text2 = text2.replace(/(a)/g, "b");
  $("#text").val(text2);
});

//i tried with keyup, keydown also...
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: why -1 already ????? sorry but please don't send me a link saying "this question is already answered" because i checked it before posting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `event.preventDefault`:

```js
$("#text").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.key === "a") {
    event.preventDefault(); // <================
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

That just prevents the `a` from appearing. If you want to insert `b` instead of `a` when the user types `a`, you'll need [the techniques in this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308292/inserting-text-at-cursor-in-a-textarea-with-javascript). Just calling `.val(..)` will mess up the user's cursor position (try typing in front of existing text when updating the value with `val` to see the problem).

Live example using [Tim Down's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3308539/157247) to that question:

```js
$("#text").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.key === "a") {
    event.preventDefault();
    insertTextAtCursor(this, "b");
  }
});
function insertTextAtCursor(el, text) {
    var val = el.value, endIndex, range;
    if (typeof el.selectionStart != "undefined" && typeof el.selectionEnd != "undefined") {
        endIndex = el.selectionEnd;
        el.value = val.slice(0, el.selectionStart) + text + val.slice(endIndex);
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = endIndex + text.length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && typeof document.selection.createRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.text = text;
        range.select();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: okay sir this is not exactly what i wanted because i tried it before but thank you

Comment: @pinug - How so?

Comment: oh i didn't see your last post yes that's it sir !

Comment: Well, all I did with the update was show an example of applying the techniques I'd already pointed to.

Comment: sir how can do this with "abc" -> "b" for instance. because event.key gets only one letter am i wrong ? :/ @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @pinug - You'd have to respond to the keyup on `c` by doing the replace. Maintaining the correct cursor position will be tricky, but possible. Give it a go. If you run into a **specific** problem, post a question with what you're trying to do and a [mcve] of your attempt.